# How to fix "Emulator: Warning: This plugin does not support application fonts" on macOS Mojave?

Tags: android-emulator

Any time I try to run a project from Android Studio (latest version) on macOS Mojave using the built-in emulator, an error comes up saying:

> Emulator: Warning: This plugin does not support application fonts ((null):0, (null))
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this sort of issue?

I've tried updating to the latest version of Android Studio. I've also tried different emulations (different API levels, different hardware, etc.). I've already tried uninstalling Android Studio and all android related files using the following commands:

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
rm -Rf ~/.android
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*
```

None of this has worked so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fonts in XML not working on emulator API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618853/fonts-in-xml-not-working-on-emulator-api-23)

Comment: you need to use a system image with Play Services installed (or use a hardware device).

Comment: I tried to run my emulator from the command-line. Running without sudo caused the same errors to appear. Surprisingly running with sudo fixed everything and the emulator booted up normally.